# Angular Material - displaying Mat-Menu on mouse-over only when condition is true

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

quick question. I want to trigger `Mat-menu` on mouse over div element with header of my component, but only when some specific condition is set to true.

I have something like this:

```
<div class="card-header"
     [matMenuTriggerFor]="comp.RejectionDetails ? rejectionDetails : null" 
     #trigger="matMenuTrigger" (mouseenter)="trigger.openMenu()" 
     (mouseleave)="trigger.closeMenu()">
  <mat-menu #rejectionDetails [class]="'mat-menu-component'"
            [hasBackdrop]="false">
      <ng-template matMenuContent>
           <div>TEST</div>
      </ng-template>
  </mat-menu>
```

It's seems to work as expected but in console it's throwing error:

> UniversalDynamicComponent.html:10 ERROR Error: matMenuTriggerFor: must pass in an mat-menu instance.
>
> ```
> Example:
>   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu"></mat-menu>
>   <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></button>
> ```

I understand that is because of passing null value to directive (when the conidition is false). But I can't figure out other solution for this problem. Maybe someone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your condition not on [matMenuTriggerFor], but on (mouseenter) event like that:

```
 [matMenuTriggerFor]="rejectionDetails" 
 (mouseenter) = "comp.RejectionDetails ? trigger.openMenu() : null"
```

Comment: you can also write the same using `(mouseenter) = "comp.RejectionDetails && trigger.openMenu()" `

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2-3 hours on this, the most easiest workaround I found for this problem is,

1. Define 2 mat-menu one for your normal behavior and other menu to
   show nothing. (reason to do this is because "matMenuTriggerFor"
   cannot be false or null it needs to have a mat-menu object)

   ```
   <mat-menu #sub_menu="matMenu">
     <button>menu-button 1</button>
     <button>menu-button 2</button>
   </mat-menu>

   <mat-menu #fake_menu="matMenu" class="fake-menu"></mat-menu>
   ```
2. now put a condition on your "matMenuTriggerFor" like this:

   ```
   [matMenuTriggerFor]="your-boolean-condition ? your-normal-menu : fake-menu"
   ```
3. On CSS just write

   ```
    ::ng-deep {
      .fake-menu {
        display: none;
      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [class] to hide/show your menu:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [class]="yourCondition ? 'hide_menu' : ''" >
    <ng-template matMenuContent >
        <button mat-menu-item>item</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

In your CSS, you can do the following:

```
 ::ng-deep {
   .hide_menu {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```